# Grub 2 installed on-partition - how to not embed it

Tags: ext4, grub2, macintosh

My friend installed ArchLinux on a MacBook Pro alongside Mac OSX and Windows to try it. He's power user, so I only needed to help with the bootloader. Arch Linux's [described installation of GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook) did not work (grub did not detect the 4th GUID partition it was installed on).

I heard that with [EFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface) GRUB 2 works, and it did. The problem is that it required embedding in an ext4 partition that had too little space for it. Is it possible to install GRUB 2 on an ext4 partition without embedding?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet on Mac hardware is to use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/). I've used that and it works well.

Comment: It is installed but as far as I understend it does not boot Linux directly but it have to chainload one.

Comment: Oh, right. Well, Grub 2 is getting way to weird for my tastes, so I switched to extlinux (part of syslinux package), which also now does support ext4.  It's simple and straightforward to install. It just works. http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/EXTLINUX

Comment: I've just sent him the link to extlinux.