# Extlinux boot error

Tags: macintosh

[Another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5134/305) recommended that I use `extlinux`. It displays the rather unhelpful message `Boot error`.

Why wouldn't it work? How can I debug the problem?

**Disk layout:** on `/dev/sda` *rEFIt* is installed. `/dev/sda4` is `/` and there is no separate `/boot` partition.

**Method of installation:**

```
extlinux /boot
```

**extlinux.cfg**

```
DEFAULT Gentoo
LABEL Gentoo
  KERNEL /boot/kernel
  APPEND -
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Step 1: Check extlinux.cfg file
cat /boot/extlinux/extlinux.cfg

# Step 2: Check system compatibility
uname -a

# Step 3: Check /boot partition
df -h /boot
ls -l /boot

# Step 4: Check bootloader installation
ls -l /boot/extlinux

# Step 5: Check bootloader configuration
cat /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf

# Step 6: Check boot logs and error messages
sudo journalctl -b -u extlinux
```

Comment: This is less of an answer and more places to look for answers.